# Why was my comment removed?

Tags: discussion, support, moderation

[What's the use of trains that spend 6+ hours of daytime en route?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/65795/whats-the-use-of-trains-that-spend-6-hours-of-daytime-en-route)

I posted a comment there yesterday on that *question*, don't think it was against any guidelines.  I don't see it anymore, any reason it was specifically removed for?

It was not an answer but it was directly related to the question and half an attempt at a casual answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I deleted your comment and 17 other comments, since the question attracted a lot of comments. On SE, comments are not meant to be for extended discussions. That should happen in the chat. Therefore, I deleted all the comments that do not provide an answer. Your comment was kind of borderline. I might have been part of an answer, but since a previous comment by JBentley already covered the same aspect, I decided to include your comment into the deletion.

Comment: Ok, if there's more to discuss, just ping me in the chat.

Comment: Isn't it normally the procedure to move those comments into a specific chat instead of removing them?

Comment: @LisaMM you're right. I did that now.